# Magento Success.phtml Html Encoding Everything

Tags: php, html, magento

Having a problem placing analytics code on my success.phtml page with magento. For some reason, whenever I echo any string with a "&" in it, Magento encodes it and prints out "&", even when it is part of an IMG's src url. For example, this code :

```
<?php 
    echo '<img src="zmam=775xxxxx&zmas=1&zmaq=N&quantity=' . $item->getQtyOrdered() . '&pcode=' . $catalog_number . '&zman=' . $lastOrderId . '&zmat=' . $_subtotal . '" width=0 height=0 border=0>';
?>
```

Prints out this on the receipt page:

```
<img src="zmam=775xxxxx&amp;zmas=1&amp;zmaq=N&amp;quantity=1.0000&amp;pcode=&amp;zman=Z77436&amp;zmat=8.9500" width="0" height="0" border="0">
```

This is true for every echo on the page. I can not track anything with a number of different Analytics providers currently. I have googled for awhile now and can not find anything on the subject- so any input at all would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your & in HTML, for links and for image-urls. So if you ask me, there is no problem. I don't know, where this comes from - magento doesn't do this, but it is correct.

`<img src="http://example.com/file.php?param=123&amp;param2=123">` is the correct way to insert links.

Are you sure, that the url is correct? it looks like, there is a file missing.

And there is an echo before? not a htmlEscape? I know this are stupid questions, but I have no idead where this should come from.

You may know this error of HTML validators?

> You may have forgotten to "escape" an ampersand (&) character, thus
>   causing the validator to believe that you created a new, undefined
>   entity that starts with "&". If you wish to cause an "&" to appear
>   within text or a URL, escape it by using "`&amp;`".

Comment: Oop, just went over and fixed it up. Yeah, I tried echo'ing &amp; and magento turns it into &amp;amp;. I cant seem to get just a & to print out.

Comment: You don't want "just a &" to print out. That will, at best, cause the document to not validate, and may lead to unexpected results in some situations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I actually do want just an ampersand to print out.... The reason being that they are being used in the source URLs for images, and thus will validate and cause no issues. The ampersands are for the query string of the URLs used in analytics.

Comment: I just noticed your edit. I'd like to point out this bit I said earlier : Yeah, I tried echo'ing &amp; and magento turns it into &amp;amp;. I cant seem to get just a & to print out.